# Whatever happened to Mind Storm Labs and Alpha Omega?

Tags: history-of-gaming

Back in 2008, [Mind Storm Labs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mind_Storm_Labs) released [Alpha Omega](https://gnomestew.com/alpha-omega-how-to-gm-this-new-rpg/), which was a really unique RPG.  My group had a lot of fun with it, until we managed to find some flaws and totally break the system.  Even with that, we might have tried to patch it, but the developers suddenly vanished and the community dried up.

Now I'm wondering what happened to them.  Why did they vanish, and was there ever any explanation/commentary/retrospective from the authors?  Did someone die?  Even a statement like "we tried, but it wasn't a success and we had to go back to our day jobs" would be some kind of closure.

Comment: FWIW, I found [this review](https://rpggeek.com/thread/607298/long-look-alpha-omega) but am not sure how else to be of help ... and [I found this](http://www.mindstormlabs.com/)

Comment: Their homepage is covered with black-hat SEO links for a casino site. :(

Comment: @Quentin - Just the home page.  The rest of it seems to be intact, although anything that links to alphaomegathegame.com now goes to what seems to be someone's placeholder blog (registered as of August 2018).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Not a lot of direct evidence (Such as a statement from the creators) as to them shutting down, but I have managed to find a bunch of anecdotal and slightly more substantial evidence that they went out of business quite a few years ago.

The twitter account still exists, but last tweet was in 2012.

The [Wayback Machine](https://web.archive.org/web/20130508161725/http://alphaomegathegame.com/) as of May 2013 still redirected MindstormLabs URL to the alphaomegathegame URL, which at that time still had the forums and other links. The main couple of questions are basically "Where is everyone?"

All of the snapshots from then on are static until late 2015, when it appears the Mindstormlabs redirect was hacked and goes to a porn/prostitution type website. As noted in the comments, the AlphaOmega URL has been reacquired by a gamer who maintains a sporadic blog.

That is the circumstantial, here is the slightly more concrete evidence - I found a [google+ discussion group](https://plus.google.com/communities/103436062374641578076), where the owner of the group responds that they slowly went out of business, but does not offer evidence or a date. However, one person that evidently did free work for them responded with:

> I did a Lot of free work for them, basically implemented their system on a wiki. But the interactions with them died off, stopped communicating. (Yes, using MediaWiki and extensions you can do programming on a wiki)

So, no direct evidence that they went out of business, but all signs point to a defunct company, unfortunately.

I also found a [media publication from Satellite Logistics](https://wardcc.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/01/SatelliteLogisticsGroupWelcomesTomMcLaughlintoBusinessDevelopmentGroup.pdf), a beverage distribution company, announcing the hiring of Tom McLaughlin in 2010 -

> McLaughlin has operated in various business development roles and most recently served as managing director for Mind Storm Labs, a subsidiary of the Barrett Corporation, a multi-national holding company with sales in excess of $2 billion.

Apparently the IP still would belong with the Barrett Corporation, evidently.

Comment: "I also found a media publication from Satellite Logistics" - I assume that's a physical publication, hence the lack of a link?

Comment: @V2Blast - No, it was a PDF. I thought excerpting the pertinent part was good enough, but I went ahead and added the link.

Comment: Sounds good. Including the link helps in case people want to verify the source or get more context.